# referenced to parent form to child form

Tags: c#

I created a ParentForm. From the menu on the ParentForm I created a ChildForm from the ChildForm menu item. When ChildForm is created, I set Childform menu item on the ParentForm disabled.
What do I have to set and reference to make the ChildForm menu item on the ParentForm
enabled when closing ChildForm.

Thanks

Tamas

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class myParent : Form {
      ...
      ...
      public myParent {
             initChildren();
      }
      void initiChildren() {
          myChildAlpha = new ChildForm();
          myChildAlpha.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(enable_menu)    
      }
      void enable_menu(object sender,FormClosedEventArgs e) {
          //check if sender == ChildForm -> if so enable the proper menu
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ParentForm form;
    public ChildForm(ParentForm _form) //pass ParentForm as Parameter
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form = _form; //save Parameter to variable form
    }
    //raised when Form was closed
    private void ChildForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //set item to public modifier in properties window or specify getter and setter, then you can set it set it to enabled again like this
        //Pseudo: form.menu.item.enabled = true;
    }
    //create Instance of ChildForm like this "ChildForm child = new ChildForm(this);"
```